# How can I have a python file automatically respond to an input() from another file

Tags: python

My code looks like this:

File A:

```
import os
inputA = input("Input: ")
os.system('InputTest.py')
```

File B:

```
inputB = input("Input: ")  # <-- I want this to automatically get filled in with inputA
print(inputB)
```

I want to have the input variable from file A fill the input request in file B (in the terminal).

Comment: You might want to use `pexpect`

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but why don't you use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)? i.e.:

#### script A

```
import os, sys

inputA = input("Input: ")
os.system('python /full/path/to/InputTest.py ' + inputA )
```

#### script B (InputTest.py)

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure of what you want to do,but,if u need to connect 2 scripts,maybe you can use socket lib,and make  client-server connection.
Or,to thing a "different" solution,you can make a text file,where one script write and another script read.
Another solution can be,when you get input,you can open other python file and send input with pyautogui lib.